# JavaScript regular expression to have unique contents

Tags: javascript

I want a regular expression which allows

`__$1__, __$2__, ... __$9__`

or

`__$an alphanumeric word up to 6 characters__` 
in a string...

I have tried with below expression but it's not working as required:

```
/^.*(\_\_\\$[1-9]{1}\_\_|\_\_\\$[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,6}\_\_)\1{1}.*$/;
```

Also, there should not be any repeated `$` content.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
/__\$([0-9]|[A-z0-9]{1,6})__/
```

or

```
/__\$([0-9]|[A-z]{1}[A-z0-9]{0,5})__/
```

Comment: I assume he wants the `<` and `>` to be there in the case of a word. And he said alpha**numeric**.

Comment: I have edited  my question... There can be either $following numerics(1 to 9) or $ following alpha numerics(Max 6)

Comment: I fixed my answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with:

```
/__\$([0-9]|[A-z0-9]{1,6})__/
```

This should fit your requirements except for:

> Also, there should not be any repeated $ content.

I guess this can't be accomplished using just Regular Expressions, at least as far as I know...